# Unable to fetch specific data from table using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Here's the code snippet I've written :

```
String url = "https://www.premierleague.com/tables";

doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
table = doc.select("table").first();

rank = table.select("td[id=tooltip]").iterator(); //Position
team = table.select("td[class=team]").iterator(); //Club
points = table.select("td[class=points]").iterator(); //Points
```

I can fetch data like position, Club and Points because I can identify them with class name or ID but I'm not able to fetch other data like Played,Won,Draw,Loss,GF,GA,GD etc

Can someone help me  ?

Comment: Is this resolved? Then please accept the given answer, otherwise post a follow up question in the comments. Regarding "off-topic": don't agree, the problem is: how to select elements without id or class and all information is given in the question.

Comment: Answer accepted, sorry for the late response. And yes, it isn't off-topic, agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use selectors based on the structure, see this example for first entry in column *won*: http://try.jsoup.org/~camnKp8NJYL0meyfIRXEtV8E5B4

To get the selectors right you can use the developer tools in google chrome (f12), right click on an element in the Elements tab and choose `Copy -> Copy selector`.

```
Iterator<Element> gamesPlayed = table.select("tbody tr > td:nth-child(4)").iterator();
Iterator<Element> gamesWon = table.select("tbody tr > td:nth-child(5)").iterator();
Iterator<Element> gamesDrawn = table.select("tbody tr > td:nth-child(6)").iterator();
Iterator<Element> gamesLost = table.select("tbody tr > td:nth-child(7)").iterator();
```

Alternatively parse the table row by row and store the cell values as in the following example:

**Example Code**

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36";
String url = "https://www.premierleague.com/tables";

Document doc;
String position, club, played, won;

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).get();

    Element table = doc.select("table").first();

    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {

        Elements cells = row.select("td");

        if(cells.size()<5) continue;

        position = cells.get(1).select(".value").first().text();
        club = cells.get(2).select(".long").first().text();
        played = cells.get(3).text();
        won = cells.get(4).text();

        System.out.println(position + " " + " " + club + "\n\tplayed: " + played + " won: " + won);

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
1  Chelsea
    played: 21 won: 17
2  Arsenal
    played: 22 won: 14
3  Tottenham Hotspur
    played: 22 won: 13
4  Liverpool
    played: 22 won: 13
5  Manchester City
    played: 22 won: 13
...
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example how that would be used in my code ?

Comment: @CodePlorer See updated answer.

Comment: But this isn't useful for me, I need data from individual fields mapped to GUI elements. For example, textField1 --> matches played by team ranked 1, textField2 --> matches played by team ranked 2 . I can easily do that with Iterator using next()... Can you help with that?

Comment: It is example code. Simply store the additional fields in an object and use a map to store the object as the value using the team name as the key. The example code demonstrates how to extract the information, storing and using the data depends on your design.

Comment: @CodePlorer see updated answer regarding selectors for the iterators.